# How can I target a string in an array in Java?

Tags: java

I want to make an options window where a `JOptionPane` is opened, the user goes through it, and it sets options. I have a problem on lines 10-14 of the following code, though.

```
if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {   
   Object[] possibleValues = { "Trails (Broken)", "Invicibility" };
   Object selectedValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
           "Choose one", "Input",
           JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null,
           possibleValues, possibleValues[0]);

   if (possibleValues[0] != null) {
       Object[] options = {"True", "False"};
           JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                   "Press True To Make It True And False For False",
                   (String) possibleValues[0], JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                   JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
       if (options[0] != null) {
           Options.OP_TRAILS = true;
       } else if(options[1] != null) {
           Options.OP_TRAILS = false;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: `possibleValues[0] != null` ... base on your available code, how can this ever be `false`?

Comment: I think you need to have a read of the [`JOptionPane` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) and [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) in order to understand what is been returned to you

Comment: what do you mean i am kinda new to this window stuff with the `options[0]` stuff (this is to go with the first one)

Comment: What does `possibleValues[0]` actually equal?  It certainly won't be `null`

Comment: but int the drop down box for `Trails (Broken)` and `Invicibility` idk how to make it open different boxes with diferend true false values

Comment: "It doesn't work" is *never* enough information. Always say what *actually* happens and what you *expected* to happen. Additionally, please take more care formatting your code in future - use spaces instead of tabs, and use the preview to check that the code is really readable before you post.

Comment: I have to agree with former comments; I would like to help you, but I honestly have no idea what it is that you want to come of this, or how it is particularly going wrong for you. In the future, please organize your question a little more concisely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to have a read of the [`JOptionPane` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) and [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) in order to understand what is been returned to you

`JOptionPane` is providing you withing information about what the user selected.  For example...

```
Object selectedValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Choose one", "Input",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null,
                possibleValues, possibleValues[0]);
```

`selectedValue` is going to either be `null` (for nothing was selected) or one of the values from the `possibleValues` array.

`JOptionPane.showOptionDialog` will return:

> an integer indicating the option chosen by the user, or `CLOSED_OPTION` if the user closed the dialog

Something like this...

```
Object[] possibleValues = {"Trails (Broken)", "Invicibility"};
Object selectedValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Choose one", "Input",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null,
                possibleValues, possibleValues[0]);

System.out.println(selectedValue);  
if (possibleValues[0].equals(selectedValue)) {
    // Trails (Broken) was selected
    Object[] options = {"True", "False"};
    int result = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Press True To Make It True And False For False", (String) possibleValues[0], JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
    switch (result) {
        case 0:
            Options.OP_TRAILS = false;
            break;
        case 1:
            Options.OP_TRAILS = false;
            break;
    }
} else if (possibleValues[1].equals(selectedValue)) {
    // Invicibility was selected
}
```

might be more appropriate